# What information exactly was necessary to determine and announce this "debris causing event"?

Tags: debris, imaging, impact

A 1:53 PM - 19 Jul 2016 [tweet](https://twitter.com/18SPCS/status/755505904770883584) from the twitter account @18SPCS said:

> 19 Jul: JSpOC ID’d debris causing event related to @DigitalGlobe WorldView-2; 8 debris pieces but WV2 confirmed operational & maneuverable!

**Question:** Did this mean only that several new objects were detected and that back-tracking their trajectories lead to a convergence with WorldView-2 in both time and space, and this suggests that *there may have been an event?* Or does this classification require that there is some corroborating evidence of an event as well?

Spaceflight101's article [WorldView-2 Earth Imaging Satellite involved in Space Debris Event](http://spaceflight101.com/re-entry/worldview-2-earth-imaging-satellite-involved-in-space-debris-event/) says:

> The Joint Space Operations Center issued a notification on Tuesday, reporting that WorldView-2 was involved in a debris-causing event with at least eight associated pieces being tracked. No orbital data was available for the debris, however, JSpOC is including preliminary orbit information in conjunction screenings for operational satellites.
>
> Satellite operator DigitalGlobe acknowledged the JSpOC report via Twitter and said “WorldView-2 is currently operational and is performing standard maneuvering and imaging tasks.”
>
> A few hours later, DigitalGlobe shared a satellite image of Oakland, California, taken by WorldView-2 at 21:34 UTC on Tuesday, after the debris event had taken place – reaffirming that the operation of the spacecraft has not been impacted.
>
> DigitalGlobe has begun an investigation into what happened to the satellite.

[image: 18SPCS tweet screen shot] [image: WorldView-2]

**above left:** Screenshot of [tweet](https://twitter.com/18SPCS/status/755505904770883584). **above right:** Illustration of Worldview-2 from [Spaceflight101](http://www.spaceflight101.net/atlas-v---worldview-3-launch-updates.html). **both:** click for full size.

Comment: "It is unclear exactly when the event occurred or how many of the pieces, if any, are part of WorldView-2."
http://www.spaceflightinsider.com/missions/commercial/worldview-2-satellite-involved-debris-causing-event/ Would that be enough for an answer?

Comment: @called2voyage This is similar to the Spaceflight101 article I've quoted, and it refers to the same tweet that I've shown. "It is unclear exactly when the event occurred..." may simply mean "unclear to **us**" where "us" is the editorial staff at Spaceflight Insider, and it may not necessarily be unclear to JSpOC, who have the raw tracking data and the software to analyze it. However, if a) that's not the case, or b) it seems pretty clear that there is no further public information to be had, and the question is likely to be a dead end (to those in the public arena)...

Comment: @called2voyage ...then *that* could be an acceptable answer.

Comment: Yeah, I had the same concern about it possibly meaning unclear to the editorial staff, but it at least didn't come off that way to me. Well, I'll hold off on answering for now.